# Why I always get System.IO.IOException: 'Failed to bind port error mesage?

Tags: c#

I would like to create a C# grpc server in a unit test application.

```
var grpcService = new DataProviderService();

var certificateChain = File.ReadAllText("cert.cert");
var privateKey = File.ReadAllText("private.key");

var keyCertificatePair = new KeyCertificatePair(certificateChain, privateKey);

   _server = new Server
    {
       Services = { DataProvider.BindService(grpcService) },
       Ports = {
                new ServerPort(Host, Port, new SslServerCredentials(new[] { keyCertificatePair })) 
  }
    };

    _server.Start();
```

But at the last row it says: System.IO.IOException: 'Failed to bind port  for any port number I try.

Comment: What port numbers did you try?

Comment: 50052,50051,8012,8022

Comment: netstat -an | findstr :8012 says nothing for these port numbers.